# Expected value of exit time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

Let $B_t$ be $n$-dimensional Brownian motion. Let $\tau$ be the stopping time $\tau=\inf(t\in \mathbb R_+: |B_t-x| \ge r)$ with $x \in \mathbb R^n $ and $r>0$  i.e. the first exit time from a ball with radius $r$ around some point $x$.
Assume we already know $\mathbb E(\tau)<\infty$

Show $\mathbb E(\tau)=\begin{cases}
\frac{r^2-|x|^2}{n},  & \text{$|x|<r$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$

I was already able to show that $\mathbb E(\tau)=\frac 1 n \mathbb E(|B_\tau|^2)$ but I don't know how to compute $\mathbb E(|B_\tau|^2)$. 
I am used to hitting times where I can simply plug in the value for the stopped process but I am not sure what to do here. I can show the case where it equals $0$ but what about the other? It makes sense that it will be $r^2-|x|^2$ but what would be the right way to show this?

Comment: Are we to assume that $B_0=x$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins No, I think we have $B_0=0$. That is the reason why $\mathbb E(\tau)=0$ for $|x| \ge r$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\mathbb{E}(B_{\tau}^2) = \mathbb{E}[((B_{\tau}-x)+x)^2]=\mathbb{E}(|B_{\tau}-x|^2) + 2x (\underbrace{\mathbb{E}(B_{\tau})}_{0}-x) + x^2$$

Comment: Simpler than I expected.Thank you very much!

Comment: @Blablablu You are welcome.

Comment: just one more thing, with the absolute value we end up with:
$\mathbb{E}(|B_{\tau}|^2) = \mathbb{E}[((|B_{\tau}|-|x|)+|x|)^2]=\mathbb{E}(||B_{\tau}|-|x||^2) + 2|x| \mathbb{E}(|B_{\tau}|)-|x|) + |x|^2=\mathbb{E}(||B_{\tau}|-|x||^2)-|x|^2$ 

But in the very last term the triangle inequality is not in the desired direction. Which part am I missing?

Comment: @Blablablu Why would you want to do it this way ...? Just note that $$\mathbb{E}(|B_{\tau}|^2) = \mathbb{E}(B_{\tau}^2)$$ and then proceed as my hint suggests.

Comment: sorry I was just confused since we are in $n$-dimensions.
But I guess one can do it componentwise

Comment: @Blablablu Ah, I see; sorry, I totally missed that. Doing it componentwise should indeed do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I want to try another solution to see if it is correct:

I will use the [optimal stoping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) to the martingale $B_t^2-n\cdot t$ which is a martingale because is the sum of $(B_t^i)^2-t$ martingales (This is one of the tipical examples in al the text books).

Because $B_t^2-n\cdot t$ is a martingale we have that: $|x|^2-n\cdot0=E[B_{\tau_r}^2-n\cdot\tau_r]=|a|^2-n\cdot E[\tau_r]$, so $E[\tau_r]=\frac{|a|^2-|r|^2}{n}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe some argument is missing because the optional stopping Theorem only gives that $(B_{\min(t,\tau_r)}^2-n\min(t,\tau_r))_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ is a martingale.